# Use Mui to build a Search box and Submit Button, Input box is not registering any keyStrokes

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I have a simple component I'm using to render a Input field with a Button next to it. Not very complicated and so I'm really not sure why but nothing I type into the field is registered.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, InputLabel, Input, Box, FormControl } from "@mui/material";

const WeatherCitySearch = ({ city, changeCity }) => {
  const [tempCity, setTempCity] = useState("");

  const handleTextBox = (input) => {
    console.log("Search Typing ... ", input.target);
    setTempCity(input.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{city}</h1>
      <Box component="form">
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>City</InputLabel>
          <Input
            type="text"
            id="city-search"
            placeholder={city}
            onChange={handleTextBox}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => changeCity(tempCity)}>
          Search
        </Button>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};
export default WeatherCitySearch;
```

This is my first time using Mui so I'm not sure if I am using it correctly.

Comment: Hi, when you add onChange inside, it becomes controlled component. So you need to bind the value to it. so, add value={tempCity}

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Anu I think you are correct that I'm not handling the controlled component correctly. But when I have updated the <Input/> it is still not working at all.
```
<Input
            type="text"
            id="city-search"
            placeholder={city}
            value={tempCity}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log("TYPING!!! ", e.target.value);
              setTempCity(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
```